# "unleashed a torrent of bullets at/on/toward the man"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

Does any of these prepositions tell anything about whether any of the bullets hit the man or not?

> The police officer unleashed a torrent of bullets at/on/toward the man.

Answer (score 1):

“at” and “toward” have the same meaning of in the direction of the man. They alone do not imply he was hit.

“on” technically means the same, but it feels like the bullets are better aimed.

That said, if you unleash a “torrent” of bullets, that changes things. We don’t normally expect this from cops, but it’s common in drive-by shootings: if you spray a crowd with enough lead, your target is eventually going to get hit, no matter how bad your aim is.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out in the current climate that police do often fire large amounts of bullets for the same reason, and the language used when reporting it tends to disconnect the consequences from the action, in a passive "someone died" kind of way. So the OP's quote is being more explicit about the action and the intent, whether any of them hit is sort of a separate issue. I do think that "on" has more of an implication that the man was hit though (but not necessarily)

Comment: @cactustictacs That is sadly correct. There was a recent example of cops firing 42 times (at an unarmed man, in the back) and “only” hitting him 11 times. We expect better from cops, on multiple levels.

Comment: yeah I just thought it was worth mentioning since the question might be from reading some recent news, and there's uh, let's say some nuance in the language that gets used